# How create segue to ViewControllerB from TableViewCell.xib using delegates Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, xib

I am learning,
really need help!

I have  2  ViewControllers: `ViewControllerA` with `UITableView` (With `TableViewCell .h .m .xib` files) and `ViewControllerB`.

I have "connect button" `- (IBAction)goButton:(id)sender;` in `CustomCell`.

How to segue to `ViewControllerB` from `TableViewCell` using delegates?

TableViewCell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class TableViewCell;
@protocol TableViewCellDelegte <NSObject>
@required
- (void) customCell:(TableViewCell *)cell button1Pressed:(UIButton *)btn;
@end

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<TableViewCellDelegte>delegate;
@end
```

TableViewCell.m

```
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell
@synthesize delegate;
- (void) customCell:(TableViewCell *)cell button1Pressed:(UIButton *)btn;{

}

- (IBAction)Button:(id)sender {
}
```

ViewControllerA.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,TableViewCellDelegte>
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id delegate;
@end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize delegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

 [self setAllTableData];
  _tableView.delegate = self;
  _tableView.dataSource = self;
  _tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  _tableView.rowHeight = 100;

}
- (void) setAllTableData {
  //[_tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
  UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil];
  [self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
}

- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
  return 1;
}
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
  return 1;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
  //static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableViewCell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
  if (!cell) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
        cell.delegate = self;
  }

  return cell;

}
- (void) customCell:(TableViewCell *)cell button1Pressed:(UIButton *)btn{
  NSLog(@"DELEGATE IS WORK");
}

@end
```

**error: `cell.delegate = self;`Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'UITableViewCell *'**

Answer (score 0):

Update your code like below:

**CustomCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btnSegue; //Connet this button outlet to your cell in storyboard
@end
```

**CustomCell.m**

```
#import "TableViewCell.h"

@implementation TableViewCell
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

}
```

**ViewControllerA.m**

**`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

   TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.btnSegue addTarget:self action:@selector(yourSegue:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  //If you want some data to get fetch from cell so use this tag concept
     cell.btnSegue.tag = indexPath.row;

  }
  return cell;
}
-(void)yourSegue:(UIButton *)btn
{
 //Write your segue code here
 int tag = btn.tag;
 //Use above tag to get data which is on your selected cell

}
```